# Raspberry Pi 4 - gstreamer playback

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to playback a FHD H.264 video on my new Raspberry Pi 4 B - 4GB with Buster using gstreamer.
I installed gstreamer from the repo, version 1.14.4

This are the command and the result that I tried:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Setteventi.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! kmssink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKMSSink:kmssink0: display-width = 1920
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKMSSink:kmssink0: display-height = 1080
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
qtdemux.c(6073): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///root/livion_test_media/Setteventi.mp4 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayGBM\)\ gldisplaygbm0";
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/quicktime, variant=(string)iso
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstMultiQueuePad:sink_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/v4l2h264dec:v4l2h264dec0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/v4l2h264dec:v4l2h264dec0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad1: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLUploadElement:gluploadelement0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLColorConvertElement:glcolorconvertelement0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLColorBalance:glcolorbalance0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLImageSink:sink.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLColorBalance:glcolorbalance0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLColorConvertElement:glcolorconvertelement0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLUploadElement:gluploadelement0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0.GstGhostPad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad5: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad4: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./livion_test_media/Setteventi.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! kmssink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = file:///root/livion_test_media/Setteventi.mp4
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/quicktime, variant=(string)iso
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstMultiQueuePad:sink_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1001e67640028acd940780227e5c05a808080a0000003002000000641e30632c001000568e93b2c8bfdf8f800, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayGBM\)\ gldisplaygbm0";
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/v4l2h264dec:v4l2h264dec0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/v4l2h264dec:v4l2h264dec0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1088, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)25/1
```

No one of those work, anything is showing.
So I installed gst-doc and try to compile and run the tutorial.
The playback-tutorial-1 show something but with horrible quality.

Any suggestion? I have to install any plugins or library?

The next step will be to playback 4K video, is it possbile with gstreamer? I didn't find anything to play 4K video except to install KODI and I don't wont to install it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the net I've found out that using omx from gstreamer in rpi is passe. I don't have any more details, as I'm still researching the subject myself, but try using v4l2:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=jellyfish-15-mbps-hd-h264.mkv ! matroskademux ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! kmssink
```